# Условие выполнения шага в TeamCity

Tags: jetbrains, непрерывная-интеграция, teamcity, build-automation

Есть TeamCity и конфигурация билда из нескольких шагов,
Есть ли возможность по каким либо параметрам пропустить один из шагов.
Т.е. есть репозиторий откуда тянутся 2 ветки (master и dev)
И в случае если изменения произошли в ветке dev необходимо выполнить 1 дополнительный шаг и дело в том, что это не должен быть `Command Line` или `PowerShell` (в котором, можно обработать какие то переменные), а должен быть например runner `MSBuild` или `SMB Upload`
Очень не хочется делать отдельную конфигурацию билда, изза этой особенности.

примеры сценариев

1) изменения в ветке master:

а) забираем изменения и билдим проект (vs.sln) (MSBuilder runner)

б) деплоим что получилось на сервер masterServer (SMB Upload runner)

2) изменения в ветке deploy:

а) забираем изменения и билдим проект (vs.sln) (MSBuilder runner)

б) деплоим что получилось на сервер developServer (SMB Upload runner)

в) деплоим что получилось на сервер homeServer (SMB Upload runner)

смысл в том что сейчас эти сценарии билдятся при помощи одной конфигурации 
[image: конфигурация]

и делать 2 разных или по количеству веток очень не красиво и тяжело поддерживаемо

Comment: Не нужно смешивать билд и деплой в одной конфигурации. Делайте разные конфигурации (CI/deploy) и настраивайте зависимости.

Comment: @andreycha по скрину видно что конфигурации разные, наследовать параметры так же знаю как (точнее до них добраться), видимо просто придется отказаться от сахара в виде `runner msbuild` и `smb upload` и делать все через `cmd` или `powershell`. У меня так же надо делать разные трансформации webconfig для этих случаев

Comment: Вы же написали, что "эти сценарии билдятся при помощи одной конфигурации". Если использовать разные конфигурации, то отказываться от MSBuild/SMB runner'ов не придется.

Comment: Это был как пример ситуации на котором проще понять проблематику сабжа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно. но лучше для разных веток иметь разные проекты. а проекты можно зашаблонить.

У меня аналогичная ситуация: дев деплоится всегда, а мастер по требованию с указанием хоста. На продакшн деплоится тогда и только тогда, когда лично руками укажу версию и хост

[@andreycha](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/106/andreycha)

> Нет, условное выполнение шагов TeamCity не поддерживает. Поэтому и
>   появляются кастомные шаги с PS скриптами/отдельные конфигурации :). (В
>   вашем случае отдельные конфигурации в любом случае являются правильным
>   подходом.)

создаем переменную branch в конфигурации, которая содержит имя бранча.

```
branch=%teamcity.build.vcs.branch.<VCS root ID>%
```

подробно [тут](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

далее создаем **Command Line Build Step**, в котором пишем условие проверки бранча

```
if (%branch% -eq "dev") then 
 do something
```

таким образом, скрипт выполнится, если это - dev бранч

**UPDATE**

предлагаем использовать такой подход:

- отдельная build конфигурация, которая билдит оба бранча
- отдельные конфигурации, которые деплоят мастер  и дев

конфигурации можно шаблонить, шаблон использовать для дева и мастера. 
Дев, помимо шагов, описанных в шаблоне, имеет дополнительный шаг деплоя

другой подход при вашей схеме:

создать другую конфигурацию, которая будет работать только для дева (настраивается через бранч фильтр). настраивается через зависимости.

спасибо [@andreycha](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/106/andreycha) за то, что напомнил о разделении шагов.

третий подход **НЕ РЕКОМЕНДУЕТСЯ**:

всегда можно узнать, как "раскрывается" команда **SMB Upload**. Это как всегда программа с параметрами. Эти параметры можно увидеть в **Build logs**. 
копируйте. параметризуйте конфигурацию, выполняете как **Command Line**

Comment: в том то и дело что это не должен быть `Command Line Build Step`, а должен быть например `MSBuild Build Step` или `SMB Upload Build Step`

Comment: @sag3ll0  тогда можно создать зависимость на другую конфигурацию, которая будет смотреть только на dev(делается это через бранч фильтр)  и выполнять дополнительный шаг только для дева.

Comment: Плюсую вариант с раздельными конфигурациями: CI билд, деплой билд (который выбирает сервер из параметра) и дополнительный деплой для дева через бранч-фильтр. Вообще не нужно смешивать билд и деплой в одной конфигурации. Дополните ответ, @SeniorPomidor?

Comment: @sag3ll0 у меня аналогичная ситуация. дев деплоится всегда, а мастер по требованию с указанием хоста.

Comment: @andreycha в том то и проблема что до этого меня обязали их объединить =(, я так же считаю что надо хотя бы разнести в разные ветки. и тут уже проще будет их отслеживать.

Comment: К тому же вопрос не только как это организовать, а скорее есть ли механизм в teamcity который позволяет выставлять условия на выполнение того или иного `Build Step`, есть ли вообще механизм управления этими шагами из агента (например из тех же самых скриптов cmd и powershell), на подобии изменения переменной (`Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='buildConf' value='$buildConf']"`) билда или выхода из билда с ошибкой

Comment: Нет, условное выполнение шагов TeamCity не поддерживает. Поэтому и появляются кастомные шаги с PS скриптами/отдельные конфигурации :). (В вашем случае отдельные конфигурации в любом случае являются правильным подходом.)

Comment: @SeniorPomidor вы внесите последний комментарий как начало своего ответа или, я отмечу как ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @sag3ll0 обновоил ответ. второй абзац. ты про это?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor я про фразу которая дает ответ на непосредственный вопрос сабжа  ("Нет, условное выполнение шагов TeamCity не поддерживает." из комментария @andreycha), ну а предложение по решению проблемы конечно оставить =)

Comment: @sag3ll0 done. какое решение принял ты?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor пока обсуждаю с тем, кто мне эту задачу поставил.но что то где то разделять точно придется =). То ли это будут разные конфигурации проекта (со своими трансформациями, и тогда все шаги останутся как есть, только будет на основе параметров задаваться направление), то ли это будут в гите разные ветки и тогда так же на основе параметров будет все, или как вы посоветовали через разные конфигурации построения (build configurations).

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity [не поддерживает](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17939) условное выполнение шагов. Поэтому ваш вопрос можно решить либо кастомными шагами с PS скриптами, либо отдельными конфигурациями. В вашем случае отдельные конфигурации являются правильным подходом (потому что нужно разделять CI/deploy билды), тут я полностью поддерживаю ответ @SeniorPomidor.